# how to detect a part of expression in a string in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab, text, strcmp

I type as a user name `v = ddd` for example. I have then a string, name, of this shape:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee
```

and I want to detect if in my string name there exist (between dots) such string like from my input. How can I do it?

I tried the idea with

```
str = 'REGEXP.helps.you.relax';
user = 'el'
[m s e] = regexp(str, '\w*user\w*', 'match', 'start', 'end')
```

but I get error, because cannot put the variable `'user'` this way inside regexp. 
How can I do it correctly? Or maybe is there any simpler idea?

Thanks!!

Comment: is `el` really an acceptable match, or shouldn't it be `help`?

Comment: @Jonas Why so? Why not `relax`?

Comment: @yoda: because I stop parsing once I found a match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to regexes, you can use [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html), which finds one string inside another. It returns the starting index of the child string (if it exists) and an empty matrix vector. Since you only need to check if that string exists or not, a simple solution is:

```
~isempty(strfind(str,user))
% ans = 1
```

Comment: what if I want to compare with one cell from a 2x2 cell, for example ~isempty(strfind(str,user(2,2))), doesn't work ... i get such an error: If any of the input arguments are cell arrays, the first must be
a cell array of strings and the second must be a character array.

Comment: @user1578163 I don't follow... could you update your question with an example illustrating your problem?

Comment: question is the same. but try to put into workspace this: user{1,1} = 'al', user{1,2} = 'el', user{2,1} = 'ul', user{2,2} = 'ol'. if I want then to compare user{1,2} with the string, your answer doesn't work, i get an error. how should i write it then?

Comment: @user1578163 `cellfun(@(x)~isempty(strfind(str,x)),user)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `['\w*' user '\w*']` as your second argument, and it should work.